# Elemental damage versus weapon type damage

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I have collected a number of higher damage weapons which all seem to be based on Light damage, such as the [Durandal](http://ff15wiki.com/wiki/Durandal), but I've also found that most animals are resistant to this damage type.

Here is a Voretooth, as an example. I've put in some example weapons too for each scenario from my collection of weapons.

[image: Voretooth monster details]

As I see it, I have four options in this scenario.

1. Downgrade my weapon, to use a weapon which is the correct type, but not element.

   - Eg, Drain Lance III (195)
2. Use the right type of weapon, but the wrong element

   - Eg, Radiant Lance (205) Light
3. Right weapon and element

   - Eg, I don't have a Fire Lance :(
4. The right element, but wrong type (least likely)

   - Flame Tongue Sword (117) Fire

A more challenging example might be a Marshmallow.

[image: Marshmallow]

My question is, will using a higher damage weapon type, of the wrong element (Case 2) yeild higher DPS, than using a lower damage weapon of the correct type and element (Case 1 or 3)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, your best option is to choose a weapon to **avoid resistances, *then* seek weaknesses**. If an enemy is weak against one aspect of your weapon, but resistant to the other, the resistance overrides the weakness and you will suffer a damage penalty.

For your example, the Voretooth is weak against spears, shields, and ice, but resistant to holy and fire.

You will get a damage bonus if you attack it with:

- Spears and shields **unless** they are Fire or Holy
- Ice weapons of any kind (since the Voretooth has no resistances to weapon types)

You will get a damage penalty if you attack it with:

- Holy weapons of any kind (even spears and shields)
- Fire weapons of any kind (even spears and shields)

Since you'll get a damage penalty (of roughly 50%) with the Radiant Lance, you're better off switching to the Drain Lance, even though it has a lower power.

If you have no available weapons which will not have a penalty (such as in the case of the Red Giant), use Royal Arms and/or Armiger, which deal full damage to all enemies.

Comment: I don't feel this actually answers my question. Can you focus more on the actual damage penalties, bonuses and provide some examples.

Comment: Ah well, it seems to be good enough for the community. Even if the Radiant lance was 300 (with 50% penalty) = 150, and the Drain lance was 120, you'd still be better with a Radiant Lance.

Comment: Why not seek to exploit weaknesses? How much is the bonus? Is there an extra bonus if it matches multiple weaknesses? Is there an extra penalty if it matches multiple resistances?

Comment: @Kat I'll clarify. Avoiding resistances is more important than exploiting weaknesses because if an enemy is both weak and resistant to your weapon, the resistance overrides the weakness and you get a penalty.

Comment: @TimC What about scenarios such as a Red Giant which is resistant to all weapons and elements except Light?

Comment: @DavidYell Addressed in the last sentence of my answer. The Red Giant will take reduced damage from all weapons - even those with the Light property (except for Holy, but that's a straightforward case and people who have it will know). My recommendation, in my answer, is to use Royal Arms or Armiger against Red Giants, because they have no damage type and hence deal full damage.

Comment: Light and Holy are the same thing btw

Comment: @DavidYell I was referring to "Light" as the damage type and "Holy" as the dodge ability on the Ring of the Lucii. :)